# Session variables lost after header redirect

Tags: php, session, redirect

Bear with me if this looks similar to other questions posted here, I have already gone through all answers provided but not has solved my problem. I've reduced my problem to the bare minimum.

1. I have two pages (page1.php, page2.php)
2. Page1.php creates a session variable and if the session variable is set it then sends the browser to Page2.php
3. On page2.php the browser is supposed to display the value of the session variable set in Page1. php
4. My problem is that page2.php views the session variable as not set.
5. I have tried all the solutions posted by other users on stack overflow as you can see from my code below:

---

**Page1.php**

```
<?php
//start the session
session_start();

//set the session
$_SESSION['mysession'] = "Hello";


if(isset($_SESSION['mysession'])){
    //redirect the person to page 2
    session_write_close();
    header("Location: page2.php?PHPSESSID=".session_id());
    exit();
} else {
 echo "Session Not Set";
}
?>
```

**Page2.php**

---

```
<?php
//start the session
session_start();
session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']);

if ( isset ($_SESSION['mysession']) )
   echo $_SESSION['mysession'];
else
   echo "Session not set!";
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you let the session start without sending/setting id? header("Location: page2.php"); in page1 and //session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']); in page2

Comment: Is the session extension configured to read out the `PHPSESSID=` parameter? (You don't usually micromanage that yourself). What's the redirected URL? Did you test it with just cookies? Did the cookie get set?

Comment: Is the second page in the same domain ?

Comment: kgb if I don't set the session_id I still can't view the session

Comment: @HarryKaranja - can you check and make sure that your browser is actually getting a cookie from the first page?

Comment: @mario I'm not sure I follow the question, but I set the PHPSESSID as one of the solutions I found on this site, same result if I leave it out. How can I test it with just cookies though?

Comment: @Razvan yes it is in the same domain

Comment: @andrewsi how do I test that?

Comment: @HarryKaranja - set your browser to alert you whenever a cookie is set. You should also be able to examine the contents, so you can be sure that you're looking at the right cookie, too.

Comment: Is your browser set to accept cookies from your site ?

Comment: @andrewsi I've confirmed that cookies are being set correctly by the browser

Comment: @Razvan yes the browser is accepting cookies from the site

Comment: Just to mention: 1. the code works just fine on my local PC but fails on the hosting server. 2. I've tried with different browsers chrome, firefox, and safari all with same results. 3. I've even tried with different ISPs

Comment: After contacting the hosting provider the problem seems to be resolved, they don't admit it but I suspect it was a configuration issue. I have also found this [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q176113][1] which might be of help to those hosting on Windows platforms


  [1]: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q176113

Answer (score 3):

session_id() needs to be called before session_start()

> If **id** is specified, it will replace the current session id.
> session_id() needs to be called before session_start() for that
> purpose. Depending on the session handler, not all characters are
> allowed within the session id. For example, the file session handler
> only allows characters in the range a-z A-Z 0-9 , (comma) and -
> (minus)!
>
> **Note**: When using session cookies, specifying an id for session_id()
> will always send a new cookie when session_start() is called,
> regardless if the current session id is identical to the one being
> set.

[session_id()-Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)

You've also might check whether you'll have cookie based authentication set.

Be aware that if users post the url, they might carry the session to another client.

Comment: The session_id querystring was only added as a workaround in case the cookies were not being set (a solution I saw somewhere in this site) however even when I leave it out, I get the same results.

Comment: php will do this for you, if there are no cookies set, so no need to worry. check http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies

Comment: thanks, checked using phpinfo() and session.use_cookies is set to On

Answer (score 1):

On `page2.php`, interchange the first 2 lines. Change

```
session_start();
session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']);
```

to

```
session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']);
session_start();
```

See the `Parameters` section here..http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Comment: Thanks. I've interchanged the lines but get the same result, "session not set"

Comment: see my comment about whether you may have a cookie based session handler active interferring with your manual setting, i believe thats the case.

Comment: @mightyuhu thanks, how do I do that? I should also mention that 1. the code works just fine on my localhost 2. I've tried it across different browsers on the hosted server with the same results

Comment: @HarryKaranja - can you do a `print_r($_SESSION);` right on the top of the file `page2.php`, before any other code, even `session_start()` and see if any session is present.

Comment: @Pushpesh nothing is printed on the browser when I place that code at the top of the page, except for "Session not set"