# Session variables lost after redirect (using header)

Tags: php

I have been learning PHP and MySQL for some time now and I encountered a problem.
I have created a user database (MySQL), login form and page where you are supposted to be redirected after succesful login.

Login page

```
<?php 

require_once 'login.php'; //connecting to db
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)
or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

session_start(); //
if (isset($_POST['username']) &&
isset($_POST['password']))

{
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$salt1 = "qm&h*";
$salt2 = "pg!@";

$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) die("Wrong username or password.");

elseif (mysql_num_rows($result))
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $crypt_login_pass = md5("$salt1$password$salt2");
    if ($crypt_login_pass == $row[2])
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $crypt_pass;

        header("Location: index_account.php");
        exit;
    }
    else {
        die("Wrong username or password.");
    }   
}
}
?>
```

The code ran flawlessly until I added the `header("Location: index_account.php")`. I used to have there just `die("You are now logged in.")`.
And here is the page you are supposted to be redirected to:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) &&
isset($_SESSION['password']))
{
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];

echo "Your username is '$username'
and your crypted password is '$password'.";
}
else echo "Please <a href=index.php>click here</a> to log in.";
?>
```

All this code is running on localhost.
The problem is that the $_SESSION['username'] and $_SESSION['password'] won't transfer to the second page (index_account.php). I have read many post and the most similiar I've found is this: [Session variables lost after header redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397418/session-variables-lost-after-header-redirect) but without answear. 
Note that this is my first programing language (excluding HTML and CSS) and I am still very new to this.

P.S. Sorry for my Enlish. It's not my native language.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained, are [officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp) and can be [dangerous in live code](http://bit.ly/4zUdtT). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning the password using a variable that doesn't exist:

```
$_SESSION['password'] = $crypt_pass;
```

Your code defines `$crypt_login_pass` so you should use that instead:

```
$_SESSION['password'] = $crypt_login_pass;
```

Additionally, the value of `$_SESSION['username']` gets set from `$username`, which will be empty if `$_POST['username']` is not set:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) &&
    isset($_POST['password']))

{
    $username = $_POST["username"];
```

To correct this, be sure that your form has posted data in the 'username' field.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can't belive it was this simple, I was so focused on $_SESSION I just learned that I completely ignored such an obvious mistake.